# AngularJs not working with dynamic html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-directive

In my cshtml file I have a form named 'ApplyMedicalMain' and I want to show a dynamically loaded division when the form is dirty but its not happening even though the form is dirty ...

Below is my code that i got in Firefox Inspect Element:

```
<form class="form_section ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="ApplyMedicalMain" method="post" action="/MVC/Quote/ApplyMedical">
<div id="Step1_PartialView" class="QuoteStep1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Renderings/Presales/ApplyMedical.js">
<div name="Conditions" id="conditions_or_symptoms" ng-hide="ApplyMedicalMain.$dirty">
<div class="generic_error_message select">
<div class="error_icn_message"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, I have mentioned ng-hide for the division name='conditions' but it is not getting hidden even though the form has class 'ng-dirty'.And please note that the the division 'conditions' is loaded dynamically from other partial view.
can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap everything in a 'ng-app' container, here is a working example (I cleaned a bit the code)

```
<div ng-app>
    <form class="form_section ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" id="ApplyMedicalMain" method="post">
        <div ng-hide="ApplyMedicalMain.$dirty">Hidden when dirty</div>
        <div ng-show="ApplyMedicalMain.$dirty">Shown when dirty</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have wrapped it in 'ng-app' in my main division,so that is already done and ng-hide and ng-show are working with static html tags but the divisin with id 'conditions_or_symptoms'(pls refer my code) is loaded dynamically so the ng-hide condition is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why your example isn't working, but I would suggest you use css to do your hiding/showing rather than using angular's bindings:

```
form.ng-dirty .hide-on-dirty{
    display:none;
}
```

And then:

```
<form class="form_section ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="ApplyMedicalMain" method="post" action="/MVC/Quote/ApplyMedical">
        <div id="conditions_or_symptoms" class="hide-on-dirty"> ... </div>
</form>
```

That's a bit more efficient that creating a binding to the form controller's state.  But its just a thought.  There might be more of a reason why you're wanting to do the binding.